How to change PDF Print page layout in VBA code?
I am using the below VBA code to PDF-print an Excel sheet and send the PDF-print in e-mail.
Sub savePDFandEmail()

Dim strPath As String, strFName As String
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object

strPath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & trailing & "\"

strFName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
strFName = Left(strFName, InStrRev(strFName, ".") - 1) & "_" & 
ActiveSheet.Name & ".pdf"

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    strPath & strFName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=True, 
OpenAfterPublish:=False

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = Range("H8")
    .CC = Range("H9")
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Range("D1")
    .Body = Range("D2") & vbCr
    .Attachments.Add strPath & strFName
    '.Display    'Uncomment Display and comment .send to bring up an 
email window before sending
    .Send        'Keep this the same if you want to send the email 
address out on click of the button
End With

Kill strPath & strFName
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing  
End Sub

As I am weak in doing coding, I want to know how I can edit the code so that I can change the PDF-print page layout to Portrait mode and Selected Print Area.
I changed to True for IgnorePrintAreas but there's no difference to the output of PDF-print.
I hope I can the PDF-Print to be in Selected Print Area and in Portrait Mode.

The key to this is using the PageSetup property of the Worksheet you are printing. For info, see PageSetup.
Before the ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat line, add:
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlPortrait
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "B2:G16"

... but change the String passed into .PrintArea to be the area you want to print. Then also change IgnorePrintAreas:=True to IgnorePrintAreas:=False.
A separate point is that you will find it much easier to create your code and discover which properties are available if you create a Worksheet object and assign ActiveSheet to it. For example:
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ActiveSheet

... then when you type wks. you will have "Intellisense" including for the PageSetup property.

Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the check mark. This helps other users find 'answered' questions and also keeps the focus on other questions which still don't have answers.
